# Field Level Security on Email Template Not Working as Expected

Tags: email, email-template, security, field-level-security, merge-field

I'm trying to hide specific fields in an email template for a specific profile. For this, I removed the field level access for fields I want to hide for the respective profile. After logging in as that profile, those fields are still viewable in the email message preview when clicking on an email that was sent using those merge fields. Why is it that when I navigate to the object record to view the detail records, the field level access is working as expected, but when I view the sent email (that contained references to that objects detail records via merge field) I can still view the field values that I removed access to? We tested sending an email using the merge fields that have been hidden, but they were still visible in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Email is sent in the system context, not the user context, so all field data are available to the template.